# Como trabalhar com o Storage do Firebase offline?

Tags: android, firebase

Estive estudando as funcionalidades do Storage(armazenamento de mídias e arquivos) e o RealTime Database do Firebase. No caso do RealTime DB, é possível ativar a persistência de dados estando offline pelo `setPersistenceEnabled()`. Agora queria saber como faço algo parecido com isso no Storage? Preciso guardar e fornecer as referências e mídias após fazer o upload mesmo estando offline.

Obs: essa é minha primeira pergunta no stackoverflow. Caso a estrutura da pergunta esteja errada me dêem uma ajuda pra melhorar!

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente o SDK do Firebase Storage ainda não oferece esse recurso. Mas nada impede que você implemente sua própria solução para persistir os arquivos localmente enquanto o aparelho estiver desconectado.